# Transfer function estimation

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, simulink, transfer

I am trying to find a transfer function of bldc motor speed over duty cycle percent. I made two measurements for different duty cycle percentages in order to both estimate transfer function and its validation.

For the first one (%65 duty cycle step input) I got below measurement and its transfer function estimation.

[image]
[image]

For the second one (%70 duty cycle step input) I got below measurement and it transfer function estimation.

[image]
[image]

The problem is that my transfer functions are not validating each other as shown below. They do not give the same response for the same input. Can anyone explain the reason?

[image]

Comment: Please post the model you're using for the motor and for your source. The obvious answer when a model doesn't match reality is: **You need a more complex model**

Comment: I used NI & labview for the meausrements and then send the datas to matlab ident tool to find tf.

Comment: ident tool fits measurements to a transfer function of order N, that doesn't mean that the transfer is a good model for your system, just for your inputs. Dirty way to do it is taking more curves, feeding all curves at the same time to ident tool, and getting a higher order transfer function that matches all of them.

Comment: I know what you are talking about and thanks for your help. increasing its order does not give me what I am looking for . My problem is what I found from two measurents as a tf (even by hand calculation instead ident ) gives totally different tf results. increasing its order just decrease deviation but as you can see from the third graph that it is not a deviation.

Comment: To things, you're using Ident wrong. You need to fee both signals to estimate parameters of a single transfer function that minimises error to both. And you may need a third order to estimate your source response if it's not ideal.

Comment: I import two measurement into data views and then send one of them to validation data and then hit to tf to estimate. Could you please correct my mistake or  explain how to do it.

Comment: Import two measurements, select both of them, estimate a single tf, validate it. If the error is not admissible, raise the order.

Comment: I can only merge the datas and no matter the order is, there is a singularity problem in the simulation.

Comment: Are you using Ident's pre-process->merge? what simulation are you talking about ?

Comment: yes Im using Ident's pre-process->merge. and then I use the tf in a simulation to see how it runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the two measurements are very different. One has a maximum of 220, the other has a maximum of 350. This means the data acquisition is at fault, or the motor is itself variable.

Why don't you try measuring 20 times, and see if the raw data look similar?

Otherwise would need more info about your recording setup and the protocol for testing the duty cycles. It doesn't sound like a matlab or programming problem.

-- edit

Transfer functions are usually the output as a function of the input. Not functions of time.

Comment: Each measurement is implemented at different duty cycle percent not for the same dcp. I made it to validate the transfer function.

Comment: What is on the X-axis? Were you expecting the two lines to overlap? If so, why?

Comment: one for %65 step input and the other for %70 etc.

Comment: Then the result looks as expected, no?

Comment: So is there a problem?

Comment: and I use these results to validate each other for being sure about tf

Comment: the problem is my transfer functions result are totally differnt from each other. they should be matched for the same input.

Comment: can I explain my problem?

Comment: But the inputs are different, so I don't see why they should match. Anyway, a transfer function is not plotted as a function of time. the x-axis should be the dcp, the y axis should be the *steady-state* response of the motor. You need to measure at 20 different dcp's. Then plot the final speed, as a function of dcp.

Comment: for the third graph, their input same. first and second graph just for finding the tf from measurement.

Comment: Could you please explain how I can do it?

Comment: It's impossible for me to do so, since you have not provided any code examples!

Comment: there is no code, I used NI & labview for the meausrements and then send the datas to matlab ident tool to find tf.

Answer (score 0):

Transfer function estimation assumes that the system is [linear and time-invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_time-invariant_system).

Most likely the system exhibits a nonlinear response characteristic which causes a very large change in output amplitude when input is increased from 65% to 70%, so a transfer function obtained at one operating point is not valid for the other.